# Missing tick in plot

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0.1 and fixed in 11.0.1**

---

Consider this

```
Plot[Cos[π x]^2, {x, -0.5, 7.5}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False,
  Axes -> {True, False}, Ticks -> {Range[0, 7, 1], None}]
```

[image]

why is the tick "2" missing? Does the character "2" have a different size compared to other characters? Is this a bug?

I'm using version 10.0.1 on OS X 10.10.1

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior running v10.0.1 on OS X 10.10.1 on my MacBook Pro (mid 2014) or my MacBook Air (late 2010).

Comment: What happens if you use "Ticks -> {Range[0., 7., 1.], None}" forcing floating point?

Comment: it works ok on windows 7, 10.01 ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6kN7Z.png)

Comment: OK, I could reproduce this behaviour with Mma 10.0.1 on OS X 10.9.5. Actually, there is no problem for me when the graphic is first displayed at its default size (360x227) but the "2" disappear when I resize manually the graphic to a smaller size (no problem for larger sizes than the default one)

Comment: The problem occurs also if I remove the `Ticks` option. It seems the problem comes only from the setting `Axes->{True,False}`. When I set this to `Axes->{True,True}` there is no more problem.

Comment: @JohnMorganthau Still missing, [screenshot](http://imgur.com/4GlxwbP).

Comment: @SquareOne Thanks for confirming. I have the problem even using the default size.

Comment: No problem with mma version 9 on OS X, so you should probably also tag it as `version 10` only.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior running v10.0.2 on OS X 10.10.1 on my MacBook Pro (mid 2012) or my iMac (late 2012).

Comment: @Lou The problem is still here for me with v.10.0.2 (OS X 10.9.5). Did you try to resize the graphic ? For me the "2" disappears for smaller sizes of the graphic than the default one.

Comment: I see this too in version 10.1 - has it been reported to Wolfram?

Comment: @Jens yes it has been reported.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Thanks for doing that. It's very weird.

Comment: No problem with actual (10.2) version.

Comment: @mgamer Which OS are you using? It still has problem for me in 10.2 on OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: I´m using OS X 10.10.4 on a MacBook Air and aMacBook Pro

Comment: @xslittlegrass Is the issue still present in newer versions?

Comment: @xavier It's fixed in version 11.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Ticks -> {Range[0, 7, 1], Automatic}
```

Otherwise, I think Mathematica might be considering the point x = 2 on your graph as the origin of the , and from the Function Navigator, Possible Issues of Ticks states that it will not label the origin.

Switch to `Axes->{True,True}` and post the screenshot.

Also, removing `PlotRange -> All` might do the trick since it is redundant (Ticks sort of handles PlotRange's meaning in this graph)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not fix the problem (v.10.0.2 OS X 10.9.5)